# Upload .ipa file using bitrise services w/o xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa, bitrise

Since I do not own a Apple Mac, I need to upload my .ipa file
which is ready with me to iTunesConnect for putting it
on AppleAppStore ..

Not sure about bitrise workflows etc, since I have joined bitrise
short time back. Will I need to learn workflows and take
the full curve of bitrise learnings?

Is there any easy steps reckoner via bitrise just to deploy an ipa file on appleStore thru iTunesconnect without using Mac/XCode personally ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way is to build your app (`.ipa`) with https://www.bitrise.io , as that way the building & code signing of the `.ipa` is handled automatically.

If you don't want to build your app on bitrise.io and just want to upload it to iTunes Connect, you have two ways to do this depending on where you store your `.ipa` that you want to send to iTunes Connect.

1. You store the .ipa in a repository
2. You store the .ipa elsewhere (Dropbox, Amazon S3, etc.) and you want to download the .ipa from there.

In the first case:

- Create a new app on Bitrise **with the repository that you use to store the `.ipa`**. (To add a repository which doesn't include an iOS project select the `Do you want to configure the build manually?` option in the `Validation setup` section.)
- After that go to the Workflow tab, click on the Manage Workflow button and remove all the steps except the Git Clone and the Activate SSH key. (docs for accessing and managing the workflow: http://devcenter.bitrise.io/docs/add-your-first-step-to-your-apps-workflow)
- Add a Script Step and after that one of the iTunes Connect Steps (Deliver or Shenzen).
- Click on the Script Step and copy this to the content input:

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -x

ipa_relative_path_in_repository="${BITRISE_SOURCE_DIR}/relative/path/to.ipa"
envman add --key BITRISE_IPA_PATH --value "${ipa_relative_path_in_repository}"
```

In the second case:

- Create a new app on Bitrise with the repo you use to store your app.
- Go to Manage workflow
- Remove every step
- Add a Script Step and after that one of the iTunes Connect Steps (Deliver or Shenzen).
- Click on the Script Step and copy this to the content input:

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -x

ipa_download_url="INSERT_YOUR_IPA_DOWNLOAD_URL_HERE"
ipa_download_location="${BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR}/ipa-to-upload.ipa"
echo "ipa_download_location: ${ipa_download_location}"
wget -O "$ipa_download_location" "$ipa_download_url"

envman add --key BITRISE_IPA_PATH --value "${ipa_download_location}"
```

Comment: follwoing your first case steps.. I reach the " Do you want to configure the build manually? option in the Validation setup section." step.. which when passed I am asked to "'Specify the build configuration" .. and I am stuck what to enter in the three text boxes asking Branch (example: master):

Project or Workspace file path in the repository (example: ./MyProject.xcworkspace):

Scheme to build (example: MyProject):

Comment: you should specify the `branch` (usually `master`) you want to use, and just type a dot (`.`) into the other fields. You won't use those values, because you won't build your app on bitrise.io

Comment: Ok I am able to edit the workflow now and have added  Deploy to iTunes Connect Steps with Shenzen . But where should I provide my iTunesConnect credentials ??

Comment: Sorry for bothering... I have been able to figure this out  about entering credentials ..

Comment: Just for reference: the credentials have to be provided for the Deploy to iTunes Connect step, to the related inputs.